# STM32 SPI Problem with synchronization routine

Tags: c, synchronization, embedded, stm32, spi

I have problem with synchronization of SPI. Synchronization always messed up. On logic analyzer I see that signals aren't in proper position. I really don't know what can be problem. Any idea is welcome.

Hear is master code for sync:

```
#define SPI_SLAVE_SYNBYTE    0x53
#define SPI_MASTER_SYNBYTE   0xAC

    uint8_t txackbytes = SPI_MASTER_SYNBYTE;
    uint8_t rxackbytes = 0;
    do
    {
        if(HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT(&hspi1,(uint8_t *)&txackbytes, (uint8_t *)&rxackbytes, 1) != HAL_OK)
        {
            Error_Handler();
        }
        while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}
    }while (rxackbytes!= SPI_SLAVE_SYNBYTE);
```

Slave code:

```
uint8_t txackbyte = SPI_SLAVE_SYNBYTE;
uint8_t rxackbyte = 0;

do
{
    if (HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&txackbyte, (uint8_t *)&rxackbyte, 1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}
}while (rxackbyte != SPI_MASTER_SYNBYTE);
```

Comment: Can you specify you platform ? Some advises: Don't use the HAL, it is generally horrible; If you really want to, check HAL functions implementations; Use a step by step debugger can help; It looks you want use interruption: verify handler implementations.

Comment: What do you mean "signals aren't in proper position"? Is the MOSI line half a bit after the clock? If so, you have the wrong clock phase ("CPHA") setting. Could you take a screen shot with the logic analyser?